# Assuming an IAM role in python, how to do this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My aws config has a few profiles:

cat config

```
[default]
region = us-west-2

[profile sandbox]
region = us-west-2
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/team-role
source_profile = default

[profile cat]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/data-systems-role
region = us-west-2
source_profile = default
```

When I run this command from the CLI, I can assume the `cat` role by typing `--profile` at the end.

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "prod/Aurora/klondike/twou_id_ro" --profile dsci
```

But I don't know how to do this in python code. I have this code but it seems to be assuming the wrong role:

```
 session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )


{'Error': {'Message': 'User: arn:aws:sts::3333333333:assumed-role/.../user@company.com is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2...
```

I think my code is assuming the default? How do I get my python code to assume the `cat` role?
When a role is assumed, it gets temporary creds from sts right? Is that what is going on?

Comment: Use this in line one: `boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dsci')`. Session object reference can be found here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html. To test if it worked, a couple of lines code will work: `client = session.client('sts', region_name='us-east-1')`, next line: `print(client.get_caller_identity())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you should do. In your code, use the default session constructor, for example:

```
session = boto3.Session()
client = session.client(...)
```

When running on EC2 with an IAM role, your app will use credentials associated with that IAM role.

Now, ideally, you want to write code that also works on your laptop without any changes. And you can do that. The above code will work fine. It will pull credentials from your [AWS_xxx environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) or from your default AWS credentials profile.

If you're running on your laptop and you would prefer **not** to use your default AWS credentials profile but instead use a different profile that you set up specifically to assume an IAM role, like your `cat` and `sandbox` profiles, then simply provide that profile in your environment, for example:

```
AWS_PROFILE=sandbox python3 my-boto-app.py
```

Or:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=sandbox
python3 my-boto-app.py
```

But I prefer the former because the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable assignment is temporary.

Finally, please read the [boto3 credentials](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) docs. They are helpful.

Comment: under the hood, that's making an sts call? I don't want to just work on my computer... I want it to work on my deplouyment server which may not have a profile. I should just get creds from sts using the role I want to assume right in that case?

Comment: In both cases, yes it's making an STS AssumeRole call. The 2nd option is closer to what you would experience on an AWS compute instance that had been launched with an IAM role (assuming that's what you're doing). You don't want the 1st option in that case. It's common to write code that simply creates a session and client using the defaults and leave it up to the SDK credentials provider chain - on your laptop it would use your default creds, unless you wrapped AWS_PROFILE=xyz around it. On EC2 etc. it would retrieve IAM role-based creds from the metadata service.

Comment: That is what's going ot happen... the app will be deployed on an EC2 instance with a role. So why does it then need to set a profile? CAn't I write code that makes a call to STS directly? What does setting AWS_profile do for me? What does setting this environment variable change? Would my ec2 instance have a aws/config file with a profile which points to a role?

Comment: See the credentials docs to understand all the options (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html). You don’t need to set a profile on EC2. That example was how to use environment variables, specifically AWS_PROFILE, so that when you run your code on your laptop it can assume the desired IAM role without you having to code it explicitly in your app. In that way the same code can work on both laptop and in EC2.

Comment: But basically what I'm asking is that AWS_PROFILE can only work with a local config file with the profile. the profile to my understanding is a logical grouping of configs. But when my app is deployed to EC2, what needs to happen?

Comment: In EC2 the assumption here is that the machine has a role that has the proper policies to access AWS services like AWS secrets right so it won't need to assume another role to get AWS secrets right?

Comment: Yes, correct. You would only use AWS_PROFILE locally. You would not use it on EC2. I've tried to clarify my answer. It was challenging to compose and format earlier from a cellphone.